# High availability : Jobs not getting submitted immediately after name node fail over

Tags: hadoop-yarn, high-availability

We have an application configured for high availability.

Of the 2 nodes one of them is made active (say NN1) and other one's (say NN2) NameNode process is killed. So now NN1 is active.

Now we submit a mapreduce job , and the logs keep saying

**"Application submission is not finished, submitted application application_someid is still in NEW_SAVING"**.

This happens for about 17 minutes and then the job gets executed successfully.
So which means the fail-over has happened and NN1 is active. But why does it take so long?

The yarn nodemanager logs says :

INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: . Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)

Can somebody please explain as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the cause of this problem,
But restarting the yarn service help me solve this problem.